# "The" before proper nouns in technical writing

Tags: articles, proper-nouns, tech-writing

Should I use **"the"** before proper nouns? 
I would like to skip it, will it be grammatically correct?

**Example:**
MicroApp receives **the** SL Recovery Key, **the** LF Service Key, and **the** Auth Key to control user transactions.

In my case, the **proper nouns** are the names for **software components**.
In comparing with other applications, the names are unique: other apps use different names for software components.
Within my application, the names aren't unique: every name represents the class of objects: LF Service Key is a name for every TL Service Key for every app user.

I am describing software components in general (their functions, threats, compatibility, etc.), not for every user.

Many thanks in forward!

Comment: Why do you believe these are proper nouns?

Comment: I am non-native speaker with rich fantasy) Maybe I should relate them to proper names

Comment: The definite article is always correct, since every executing program is an instance created from a type.  Loading the executable file is like stamping out a cookie with a cookie cutter. A program component is usually not unique enough to warrant a proper noun, and although there are exceptions, IMHO you should write your draft *with* the articles and allow the reviewers to revise them in line with your company's general usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about these being proper nouns, but I do believe that based on your description, "the" should be used before each key as you've shown them above

Comment: Proper or not, all nouns require articles. If the reference is specific, *the blahnoun* will be necessary; if it’s generic, *a blahnoun*. Further
*Proper* nouns always and *improper* nouns never require capitals.
Nothing else you mention makes any difference.
Mary, please remember articles are one of the most-difficult aspects of English for non-natives to learn; particularly mid-Europeans… they’re difficult purely because they seem wholly unnatural.
Non-natives simply have no basis for comparison. *Technical* has no place here.

Comment: You're welcome and FMI, what's your native land or language, please?

Comment: Ukraine, Ukrainian & Russian